# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net

I'm getting the following error when trying to run my asp.net website in a browser:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

**Module**  IIS Web Core

**Notification**    Unknown

**Handler** Not yet determined

**Error Code**  0x8007000d

**Config Error**

**Config File** \?\C:\inetpub\vhosts\======\httpdocs\web.config

**Requested URL**   http://======:80/index.aspx

**Physical Path**

**Logon Method**    Not yet determined

**Logon User**  Not yet determined

(==== to hide sensitive data)

**Config Source**

```
-1: 
0:
```

Why am I getting this error? Other sites on the same server are working fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be indicating that the configuration file has problems; does the file exist? are its contents valid?

Comment: I thought this, I checked the web.config file. Everything seems fine.. :S

Comment: I wonder if you've edited or even just opened the config file in a different editor; perhaps it's ANSI encoded, for example? (straws being grasped!)

Comment: Looks like it might have been an issue with the web.config. I've replaced it with an entirely new one after many attempts at trying to locate the bug, and now the sites working fine. Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a bit strange, I will start with [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). I will enable tracing for `Status code: "200 - 999"`. I will see at what state will IIS Web Core fail. There has to be some issue with the config file which is giving this incomplete error.

You can check [Troubleshooting HTTP 500.19 Errors in IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webtopics/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7) for more guidance.